# How is this for statement true?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```py
number = [1,2,3,4,63,2]
max = number[0]
for large in number:
    if large > max:
        max = large
print(max)
```

This Python code prints the largest number in a list and it works, but I am not sure how it works. On the 5th line when `max = large` I am not quite sure that this if statement is true in the first place because the first item in the list is not bigger than `max` but it is equal to it.

Comment: so it will fail for the first item: it's testing `1 > 1` which is `false`. But the next time through the loop, it does `2 > 1` which is `true`, so `max` becomes `2`. Try stepping through your code with a debugger, it should make it more obvious what's happening.

Comment: Try working through what the loop is doing by hand. `max > 1` is False, but I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: `max` is a built-in function in python. It's a bad practice to declare something which overrides the built-in. You can use `max_num` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your confusion. The statement `for large in number:` assigns each element of `number` to `large` successively **no matter** what happens in the loop. Python `for` loops do not have a condition, unlike C-like `for` loops.

The statement `if large > max:` is *not* the condition for the loop to continue. It is totally independent of the loop statement. As you observed correctly, it is `False` for the first iteration, but that has no effect on what the `for` loop is doing. Only the value of `max` is not updated.

It's conventional not to use names like `max` that shadow built-in names. Something like `max_` or `max_value` is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
number = [1,2,3,4,63,2]
max = number[0]
for large in number:
    if large > max:
        max = large
print(max)
```

Explanation:
First iteration: `max=1` and `large=1` so if `1>1` then `max=large` else the max will the previous number as we assigned 1 initially.

2nd iteration: `max` will have 2.

.
.
.
4nd iteration: `max` will have 4.

5nd iteration: `max` will have 63.

6th iteration: `max` will have still 63 since 2 is not > 63.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not quite sure that this if statement is true in the first place because the first item in the list is not bigger than max but it is equal to it.

Your current loop works perfectly fine and in fact omits useless reassignment of the `max` variable.

```
number = [1,2,3,4,63,2]
max = number[0]
for large in number:      # For every item in the list of numbers
    if large > max:       # if a currently selected item is larger than the current maximum
        max = large       # assign that value of that item to be the new maximum
print(max)
```

For the first iteration you will get a `False`. For the given list all other iterations will yield a `True`. However if you add items that are equal like

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5 ]
```

you will soon discover that the current check you have is quite efficient. Why? Because if you add equality to the check (in which case your IF condition will return more times `True` including the first iteration)

```
if large >= max:
    max = large
```

you will end up with pointless reassignment of `max` every time you get to a value that is equal to the current maximum. So for the list I've given above as an example you will go through 4 reassignments that are completely useless - one for the second `1` and three for the three `4` after the first `4` (marked with `*` below):

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5 ]
     |           |  |  |
     *           *  *  *
```

There is one thing I would add to solution and that is omitting the first item:

```
for large in number[1:]:
    ...
```

For your comparison of numbers you will not see much of a difference but if you compare larger objects it will.